# Getting SRS/CRS name from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, openlayers, wms

I received a list (XML) of SRSes by request (by JavaScript):

http://gis1:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
then parse it and get a list of EPSG codes like "EPSG:1234"

How I can now get a name (description) of specific SRS like "Pulkovo 1942 / Gauss-Kruger zone 13" for "EPSG:28413"?

...or may be I can do it by OpenLayers API?

I asked this first on https://stackoverflow.com/q/41672346/7424390 but then I saw that specfic forum exists so just in case I duplicate here

Comment: Cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/41672346/820534 where it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to convert EPSG codes in to human readable names is to look them up on http://epsg.io - so you could download http://epsg.io/28413.html and parse it in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Probably easier to parse from http://epsg.io/28413.gml

Comment: Or go to the [canonical registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28413) and then parse out the name.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to receive SRSes from specific local GIS server (standard (embeded as in geoserver) + custom (my own) SRSes). Online services not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OGC CRS definition resolver, as detailed on the OGC wiki page:

http://external.opengeospatial.org/twiki_public/CRSdefinitionResolver/WebHome

So for EPSG::28413 you would use:

http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/28413 and then you can parse the XML response for the name (with XPath: `/gml:ProjectedCRS/gml:name`)

Comment: Thanks, but I have to receive SRSes from specific local GIS server (standard (embeded as in geoserver) + custom (my own) SRSes). Online services not an option.

Comment: You could perhaps install your own version of the secore software